# How could we use bisect method on Sorted dict?

Tags: python

I have a sorted map/ sorted dictionary in python.
I used SortedDict from sorted containers for this purpose.

I will be storing Integers as key, and Strings as value.
Now I want to use upper_bound / bisect method on the keys.
So that I can find value for key <= givenKey.

One method I know can be making list of keys then using bisect method, but this seems in efficient as I think copying all keys to array will take time complexity to O(N).

But if we might not have copied just used binary search on keys it would have been O(LogN) operation.

What is the better way to do it. Or which method works on sorted dicts for searching.

Answer (score 3):

`SortedDict` is implemented based on `SoetedList` in the same module. It internally uses `SortedList` to store the sorted keys:

```
>>> mp = SortedDict({random.randrange(100): i for i in range(10)})
>>> mp
SortedDict({0: 6, 8: 2, 21: 9, 40: 3, 43: 4, 51: 7, 68: 8, 83: 0})
>>> mp._list
SortedList([0, 8, 21, 40, 43, 51, 68, 83])
```

`SortedList` already has binary search methods, and when you create an instance of `SortedDict`, these binary search methods are also bound to the `SortedDict` instance:

```
# sortedlist.py
class SortedList(MutableSequence):
    ...
    def bisect_left(self, value): ...
    def bisect_right(self, value): ...
    ...

# sorteddict.py
class SortedDict(dict):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.bisect_left = _list.bisect_left
        self.bisect = _list.bisect_right
        self.bisect_right = _list.bisect_right
        ...
    ...
```

So you just need to use them directly:

```
>>> mp.bisect(40)
4
>>> mp.bisect_left(40)
3
>>> mp.bisect_right(40)
4
```

Comment: Not sure you need all the discussion about implementation when the presence of those methods is already [fully documented] (https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html). The existence of those private fields is an implementation detail that might change at any time, unlike the documented API.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct `bisect_left`, `bisect`, `bisect_right` return index of elements in `keys()`. Therefore you can access it as:

```py
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

# Create a SortedDict
sd = SortedDict({1: 'a', 3: 'b', 5: 'c', 7: 'd'})
index = sd.bisect_right(2) # get me key that comes after 1
print(index, sd.keys()[index], sd[sd.keys()[index]])

# prints 1 3 b
```

Note that index might be negative or out of range.

Answer (score -2):

I struggled with the same thing today, inspired by Mechanic Pig's answer I came up with this:

```
sd = SortedDict({
    1: "one", 
    23: "twenty three", 
    3000: "three thousand"})

for k in sd.irange(maximum=128): # iterator over all keys <= 128
    # notice that we only get keys, not (key, value) pairs
    print(k, "->", sd[k])
```

which prints out all keys <= `maximum`:

```
1 -> one
23 -> twenty three
```

`irange` has some other parameters so you can iterate descending instead of ascending, specify a `minimum`, etc.

As Mechanic Pig's answer points out, there are two slicing operations:

1. `irange`: returns keys between some `minimum` and `maximum` key
2. `islice`: returns keys in a range of ordinal indices, e.g. `islice(1, 3)` will give you an iterator that yields the second and third smallest keys

**Both only return keys**, which is a bit surprising because this is a map so we would expect an iterator over `(key, value)` pairs. The reason is both methods in `SortedDict` delegate to the `SortedList` of its keys. Hence keys only.

The documentation is quite unclear IMO because the `SortedDict` API docs suddenly switch over to telling you about `SortedList` methods. What they should clearly say is

- the `SortedDict` is implemented as a map with a `SortedList` of keys
- `SortedDict` has several methods also in the `SortedList` class
- those methods delegate to the `SortedList` of keys

So `SortedDict` is best thought of as a wrapper around a `SortedList` of keys, where each key happens to have an associated value.

Comment: The question asks for bisecting (and talks about efficiency and the desirable O(LogN)). You're not really doing that. Looks like `irange` *could* be used for that and be efficient but even then, it would just not be good (due to the existence of the bisect methods)

Comment: I read the question as "Now I want to use upper_bound / bisect method on the keys. So that I can find value for key <= givenKey." ... "What is the better way to do it. Or which method works on sorted dicts for searching."  For getting keys in a range you want irange; existing answer and your solution returns indices that need further processing. The complexity of irange is the same as islice, O(log(n)) as specified in the docs.